# Flash Builder Declarations Template

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

In Flash Builder, when you create a new mxml application is there a place to edit the actual `${declarations}` token in the code template?

I want to remove the text `<!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->` that shows up between the `fx:Declarations` tag.

Comment: You could remove the token and just put the Declarations tag in there.

Comment: What about Flex 3.x projects?  Wouldn't I then be injecting a declarations tag where it's not supported?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it.  But, in the code template, why can't you replace it with:

```
<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Thus removing the comment.

Comment: I did do something like the below but I didn't want to exactly override the declarations variable as it could have some dynamic output that maybe this particular use case isn't showing:
<${ns_prefix}Declarations> 
  
</${ns_prefix}Declarations>